# I want to add a specific style to the first image but everything I have tried will not work

Tags: css, css-selectors

Trying to select the first img. I have tried using .flex-projext > img:first-child but it will not work

```
<section id="work">
        <h2 class="projects">These are some of my projects</h2>
        <div class="grid-class">
          <div class="flex-project first">
            <a href="#"> <img src="picsforportfolio1/landing.jpg"> </a>
            <p class="project">Landing Page</p>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-project">
            <a href="#"> <img src="picsforportfolio1/survey.jpg"> </a>
            <p class="project">Survey Form</p>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-project">
            <a href="#"> <img src="picsforportfolio1/tribute.jpg"> </a>
            <p class="project">Tribute page</p>
          </div>
          <div class="flex-project">
            <a href="#"> <img src="picsforportfolio1/tingdog.jpg"> </a>`enter code here`
            <p class="project">TingDog</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked with me:

```
.flex-project:first-child img
```

Here is the output:

[image]

And here is the output with object-fit applied to first child only:

[image]

Comment: i tried that and it changes the first two. im wanting to use the object-fit on the first image.

Comment: Thats weird, i tried it with object-fit and it works perfectly to the first child only, double check if you have any typos maybe in your css ?

Comment: @jch0411 I have included a screenshot for the output with object-fit applied to the first img only. This is what you are trying to do ?

Comment: this time it worked, i had to move it below the img selector in the style sheet. Thanks for your help.

Comment: yes it worked, I had to move the styles below the img selector. thanks again